# Codeigniter profile picture resize

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently struggling with the auto resizing of an oversize image.
I want 2 things to happen, #1 that the image automatically resizes to the given dimensions and 2 that it generates a thumb that can be used for example in the navbar etc..

This is the current code I got
EDITED Today

```
// avatar upload
        if (isset($_FILES['userfile']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
                    function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            //return the full path of the directory
            //make sure these directories have read and write permessions
            $this->original_path = realpath(APPPATH.'../uploads/original');
            $this->resized_path = realpath(APPPATH.'../uploads/resized');
            $this->thumbs_path = realpath(APPPATH.'../uploads/thumbs');
          }

            $this->load->library('image_lib');

            $config = array(
            'allowed_types'     => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png', //only accept these file types
            'max_size'          => 2048, //2MB max
            'upload_path'       => $this->original_path, //upload directory
            'width' => 250,
                    'height' => 250
          );

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $image_data = $this->upload->data(); //upload the image


            //your desired config for the resize() function
            $config = array(
                    'source_image'      => $image_data['full_path'], //path to the uploaded image
                    'new_image'         => $this->resized_path, //path to
                    'maintain_ratio'    => true,
                    'width'             => 128,
                    'height'            => 128
            );

            //this is the magic line that enables you generate multiple thumbnails
            //you have to call the initialize() function each time you call the resize()
            //otherwise it will not work and only generate one thumbnail
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
            $this->image_lib->resize();

            $config = array(
                    'source_image'      => $image_data['full_path'],
                    'new_image'         => $this->thumbs_path,
                    'maintain_ratio'    => true,
                    'width'             => 36,
                    'height'            => 36
            );
            //here is the second thumbnail, notice the call for the initialize() function again
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
            }
```

But Now I get these errors in browser

https://gyazo.com/4ec7360df1d3cc2703d19941583982fd

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You haven't mentioned what your problem is. Have you tried doing the thumb resize yet?

Comment: @GluePear I don't know how to do it, so I was hoping someone here could point me out in the right direction.

Comment: The error message is rather self-explanatory - it can't find the image in the given location.

Comment: In that error I can't see at all that it's saying that. it'looking in my C drive? while it should clearly look in uploads/original no?

Comment: you have used `realpath()`, so its not using the relative path.

Comment: where is the location of your uploads ?